# Installing Target Bar file in Blackberry 10 alpha Simulator

Tags: blackberry-simulator, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, blackberry-qnx, blackberry-ndk

I have question w.r.t BB10 BAR file installation in Alpha Simulator.

I created a blackberry 10 casecade application on QNX Momentics IDE. Application works fine on Blackberry 10 alpha simulator when i use the 'Simulator-Debug' mode.

I also created BAR file using 'Export Release Build' wizard from bar-descriptor.xml. BAR created successfully. Later i cleaned up BB 10 alpha simulator and able to install the bar file using vnBB10 tool. It works great.

The question here is Why the app is not running in the BB 10 Simulator When i create a BAR file using 'Device-Release' mode and signed the BAR? (Actually speaking, i installed the device-release BAR file in Simulator. I can see application icon & Splash screen. it also shows the Blackberry permissions window. But after that it stopped abruptly. There was no logs to explore)

**-> do you think 'Device-Release' Bar is only made for BB 10(Z10/Q10/Playbook) devices? not for Simulators ?**

**-> How can i create a single BAR which can run on both BB 10 Device & Simulator?**

I really appreciate you for looking into this query.

~albeee~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device-Release and Device-Debug will build arm binaries while Simulator-Debug will build x86 binaries.  Essentially, the processor between real device and simulators are completely different and you need to tell the cross compiler which architecture you are targeting.  That's why Device-Release/Device-Debug will never run on the simulator and why Simulator-Debug will never run on a real device.

There might be a way to package both architectures in one bar, but why would you want to?  The simulator doesn't require signed bars and is only for development.

Comment: Thanks for making me little confident.